# Which is best in performance java or javascript, when converting list of dates from EST to UTC format?

Tags: javascript, java, utc

I want to convert date and time in EST to UTC which i retreive from DB.So,I want to know which i can use java 8 or javascript ,so performance will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may not be a noticeble difference in terms of performance between the two languages but this is done commonly in JavaScript.